# d3js adding element using .append(function(){})

Tags: d3.js

Do you know why doing this with d3 display a circle:

```
node.append("circle")
```

But not this:

```
node.append(function () {
  return document.createElement("circle");
})
```

The DOM result is exactly the same, but the circle is not visible in the second case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element is created in the wrong namespace -- you need to explicitly specify the SVG namespace for this to work, as Javascript doesn't infer it automatically:

```
return document.createElementNS(d3.ns.prefix.svg, "circle");
```