# svg: Wrap <text> in <a> using javascript results in white page (no error)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm using [jasondavies' d3-cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) to render a tagcloud and it works fine. However, I also want all items to be clickable, and the best solution would be to wrap all `<text>` elements in xlink's `a` elements. Here is a stripped example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<body>
<svg height="60" width="125">
    <g transform="translate(62,30)">
        <text transform="translate(20,8)rotate(0)" text-anchor="middle" style="font-size: 100px; font-family: Impact; fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);">text</text>
    </g>
</svg>
<script>
window.setTimeout(function(){
    var ns = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink';
    document.querySelector('svg').setAttribute('xmlns:xlink', ns);

    var el = document.querySelectorAll('g text').item(0);
    var w = document.createElementNS(ns, 'a');
    w.setAttributeNS(ns, 'xlink:href', '/test/'+ el.textContent);
    w.setAttributeNS(ns, 'target', '_top');
    w.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
    el.parentNode.replaceChild(w, el);
}, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this results in the text element becoming invisible (in both Firefox and Chrome). What's strange is if I copy the generated SVG using the DOM inspector and paste that in a separate file; it works fine.

I have currently used a work-around by adding onclick handlers, but that is far from perfect.

Comment: You need to specify the SVG namespace. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106356/d3js-adding-element-using-appendfunction/31106599#31106599).

Comment: The only element I create is the A, which doesn't exist in the SVG namespace; it does in xlink, which is why I specify that @createElementNS ?

Comment: It does exist in SVG, see e.g. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/a-element.html

Comment: Ah, you're right; document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'a') fixes it. Shouldn't you post that as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the SVG namespace for the links, otherwise the `a` elements will not be interpreted correctly:

```
var w = document.createElementNS(d3.ns.prefix.svg, 'a');
// etc
```